# Create addon with no initial keyboard shortcut assigned

Tags: python, add-on, shortcut

From the [example here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html#bringing-it-all-together) I can create the addon which allows a custom key map

```
if kc:
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(AddCube.bl_idname, 'T', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```

I can change the initial keymap to ALT + 0 with

```
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(AddCube.bl_idname, "ZERO", "PRESS", alt=True)
```

But how to change it so it's not assigned to anything, ***yet*** has the option to assign a keyboard shortcut.

I tried

```
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(AddCube.bl_idname, "", "PRESS")
```

but that resulted in an error. And this:

```
if kc:
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
    addon_keymaps.append((km))
```

just loses the Assign Shortcut context option entirely.

Comment: Wild guess but I *think* in order to be able to assign a shortcut to an operator it must be used somewhere in the UI, maybe try to add it to a dummy panel ?